# Feeds Soap - importing items but can only add 1 item at a time?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'm having problems with using this API to get my details from:

http://api.tradera.com/v3/PublicService.asmx?op=GetSellerItems

It imports almost all fields and create nodes as it should however the "LongDescription" is not beign imported or displayed in their reponse it is only displayed as  without any content

For testing I tried to use this public service to see where is the problem:

http://api.tradera.com/v3/PublicService.asmx?op=GetItem

Using this allows me to import all single item details but it uses the parametr as the Item ID (Auction Number) and allows only 1 item at a time to be imported

But it imports the Long description as it should

So I was trying to:

1) Import all items I want with "GetSellerItems" 
2) Map ItemID into Import ID
3) Use Item ID as parametr that would be passed to "GetItem" feed parametr <-- but this part I dont know how to make

If anyone have some suggestion why the "LongDescription" may not be beign displayed in response that would be great

If not then I would need to find a way to use GetItem to import descriptions of 500 items on schedular basis

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my question by my self, In order to do that I had to create simple module

```
<?php
function feedspop_node_presave($node) {
  if($node->type == 'ubrania_a') {
      $numeraukcji = $node->field_import_id['und'][0]['value'];
      $node->feeds['FeedsWSClientFetcher']['operation_arguments']['parameters']['itemId'] = $numeraukcji;
      dpm($node, $name = NULL);
  }
}
?>
```